# Extrude two dimensional list with thickness n

Tags: list-manipulation, finite-element-method, regions, mesh, computational-geometry

I have a question concerning how to extrude a two dimensional list. There are examples in mathematica forums how to extrude but none of them (as far as i know) discussed how to do it with a list. My goal is to extrude the list with a thickness n, e.g. n = 0.3.

My list for better visualization can be found here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwt1j0wqdtcsquz/excrude_list.xyz?dl=0

Any help is much appreciated. Sorry for not providing any code but I dont have any approach at the moment.

An example of what the goal in principle look like:

[image]

Comment: I assume you mean extrude. What does it mean to extrude a list? Can you give a sample of the list here?

Answer (score 5):

#### Just vertices

So, assuming you want a set of points in 3 dimensional space, and that you're starting with a bunch of points in the plane, we can build a function that produces the set of points in 3D pretty easily:

```
extrude[data : {{_, _}...}, thickness_, initialz_:0] :=
    Flatten[{Append[#, initialz], Append[#, initialz + thickness]} & /@ data, 1]
```

(This takes a third optional argument which specifies the initial $z$ coordinate, which is by default 0.)
then

```
data = Import["excrude_list.xyz", "Table"];

extrude[data, 0.3]
```

gives the set of vertices in 3D, which you could view e.g. with `ListPointPlot3D`.

#### As a 3D volume

You found the following way to order your points into a polygon-ready list, via

```
pdata = data[[FindShortestTour[data][[2]]]]
```

Now, we'll make a `MeshRegion` by supplying a bunch of `Polygon` faces, assuming no holes.

```
meshextrude[data : {{_, _} ...}, thickness_, initialz : _?NumericQ : 0, usetour : (True | False) : True] := 
 With[{tour = If[usetour, FindShortestTour[data][[2]], Append[Range[Length[data]], 1]]}, 
  MeshRegion[
   Flatten[Transpose[{Append[#, initialz], Append[#, initialz + thickness]} & /@ data], 1], 
   Polygon /@ Join[{Most[tour], Most[tour + Length[data]]}, 
    Flatten /@ 
     Transpose[{Partition[tour, 2, 1], 
       Reverse /@ Partition[tour + Length[data], 2, 1]}]]]]
```

What this does is inline `extrude` as our point set, but with a `Transpose` so that all the `initialz` height points come first, then all the `initialz + thickness` height ones. It then uses the indices given by `tour` to traverse the lower polygon, then `tour + Length[data]` to traverse the upper polygon; then it produces rectangles in the form of lists `{i, j, j + Length[data], i + Length[data]}`, where `i` and `j` are consecutive elements of `tour`. The optional `usetour` argument (`True` by default) allows you to suppress the usage of `FindShortestTour` and simply use the data ordering.

(`FindShortestTour` duplicates the first index at the end of the list it produces, so we do indeed close up the shape. As such, though, we need to use `Most` on the top and bottom polygons, otherwise it won't export to an OBJ file.)

Then take a look at

```
meshextrude[data, 0.3]

Export["test.obj", meshextrude[data, 0.3]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One follow-up question. How would you save your extrude method in a obj file. When I type Export["test.obj", excrude[data,0.3]] i get an error.

Comment: Good question. `Export["test.obj", Graphics3D@Point@extrude[data, 0.3]]` produces an error message (also be sure to use `extrude`, not `excrude`), but seems to produce a usable `obj` file nonetheless. I'm not quite sure what the error message is for; according to the documentation it should be fine. Although the data appears in the resulting obj file, it seems to fail on import, though.

Comment: `ed = extrude[data, 0.3]; Export["test.obj", MeshRegion[ed, Point /@ Range[Length[ed]]]]` should also work, but fails to even produce an `obj` file.

Comment: Sorry yes it should be extrude. It creates a obj file but if i import the file e.g. with meshlab, I still have points instead of a solid like in the example picture. The goal would be similar to the picture  above. Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: You don't have enough information in your original list to produce a solid (or a surface). A set of points by themselves doesn't produce a surface; you need to know what the connections between them are. Often this is done implicitly by putting them in order: each point is taken to connected to the next. Mathematica uses this encoding in `Polygon`, for example. But as you can see with `Graphics[Polygon[data]]` or `ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]`, your points don't appear to be in the right order. So, they would need to be processed or reordered somehow first.

Comment: Then, to make an extruded 3D mesh, we would need to do something a bit different. I would probably answer this separately if this is the route you want to go!

Comment: That would be much appreciated if we can make a extruded 3d mesh with thickness n

Comment: First, you'd need to clean up your 2D data so as to produce a 2D polygon/mesh, which might be worth a separate question: something like "how can you turn a 2D point set into a polygon based on distance". I'm not sure what the best way to go about that is, but mathematica might have built-in functions that someone might be able to recommend!

Comment: You also seem to have some outlier points which you presumably don't want in your final object, as you can see with `ListPlot[data]`. So your question would need to also ask how to clean up the data.

Comment: I stumbled upon the built-in function data[[FindShortestTour[data][[2]]]] then Polygon works. For the outliner i would suggest to leave them at the moment.

Comment: Very nice! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ok, there you go! Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok...updated the answer, since the previous one didn't actually export.

Comment: Thanks alot. It works

Answer (score 5):

The following answer addresses how one might go about cleaning up the data provided in the Dropbox link.

## Import data

Importing and inspecting the file `excrude_list.xyz` shows 859 points with some sharp spikes.

```
(*Import and sort data by shortest tour*)
data2d = Import["excrude_list.xyz", "Table"];
data2d = data2d[[Most@Last[FindShortestTour[data2d]]]];
ListPlot[data2d, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Original data set]

## Simple cleaning

We can remove the spikes by sorting and deleting the six largest segments. Since the shape is relatively featureless, we can delete 700 points with the smallest segment lengths as shown in the following:

```
(*Delete coordinates by segment length*)
delFn = {data, n} |-> 
   Delete[data, 
    Partition[Ordering[Norm /@ (Rest@(# - RotateRight[#])) &@data, n],
      1]];
(*Deleting the six largest segment lengths will eliminate the spikes*)
data2da = delFn[data2d, -6];
(*Deleting smallest segments will space out the points*)
data2db = delFn[data2da, 700];
ListPlot[data2db]
```

[image: Simplified data]

## Find optimal eight-sided polygon

Use right-click and Get Coordinates to select the approximate vertices of the eight-sided polygon.

```
(*Right-click and use Get Coordinates to get corner points*)
spts = {{5.289011672688332, 
    0.11623578148886082`}, {10.898569507357777`, -45.94403441331893}, \
{53.050389807873884`, -44.18216615450115}, {51.44765899796833, \
-35.62452032595762}, {20.034135123819446`, -37.88977951586621}, \
{18.591677394904444`, -29.33213368732268}, {30.772431550186667`, \
-26.31178810077791}, {27.887516092356663`, 0.6196267125796595}};
```

Define some functions for the optimization:

```
Clear[p, pbnd, sdf]
(*Eight point polygon*)
p[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_, x3_, y3_, x4_, y4_, x5_, y5_, x6_, y6_, x7_, 
  y7_, x8_, y8_] := 
 Polygon[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}, {x5, y5}, {x6, 
    y6}, {x7, y7}, {x8, y8}}]
(*Constraint builder for NMinimize*)
pbnd[p_, i_, r_] := 
 ToExpression[
  StringTemplate[
    "Between[x`i`,{(`x`)-`r`,(`x`)+`r`}]&&Between[y`i`,{(`y`)-`r`,(`y`\
)+`r`}]"][<|"i" -> i, "x" -> p[[1]], "y" -> p[[2]], "r" -> r|>]]
(*Distance to polygon function*)
sdf[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_, x3_, y3_, x4_, y4_, x5_, y5_, x6_, y6_, x7_, 
   y7_, x8_, y8_][data_] := 
 With[{d = data, 
   srd = SignedRegionDistance[
     Polygon[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}, {x5, y5}, {x6, 
        y6}, {x7, y7}, {x8, y8}}]]},
  Norm@srd[d]]
```

Now we are ready to search for the eight-sided polygon that minimizes the Norm of the [`SignedRegionDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SignedRegionDistance.html) function.

```
(*Find polygon that minimizes the distance to selected points*)
constraints = Apply[And, MapIndexed[pbnd[#1, First[#2], 5] &, spts]];
poly = p[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6, y6, x7, y7, x8, 
    y8] /. Last@
    NMinimize[{sdf[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6, y6, x7,
         y7, x8, y8][data2db], constraints}, {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, 
      x4, y4, x5, y5, x6, y6, x7, y7, x8, y8}, Method -> "NelderMead"];
Show[ListPlot[data2db], 
 Graphics[{Directive[Opacity[0.25], Orange], poly}]]
```

[image: Optimized polygon]

The fit looks reasonable.

## Extrude the polygon

Now we can use [`RegionProduct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionProduct.html) to extrude the final 3D mesh.

```
(*Define Some Helper Functions For Structured Meshes*)
pointsToMesh[data_] := 
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
(*Use RegionProduct to extrude mesh*)
ℛ = 
 RegionProduct[MeshRegion@poly, pointsToMesh@Subdivide[0, 0.3, 1]]
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
Export["extrude1.obj", ℛ]
```

[image: Extruded simple mesh]

Now, we can verify that the object file can be read into MeshLab:
[image: Mesh lab simple]

## FEM approach

If you need additional detail and do not desire the simplification to an eight-sided polygon, here is an approach using `FEM`.

```
(*Import required FEM package*)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
incidents = Partition[FindShortestTour[data2db][[2]], 2, 1];
(bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> data2db, 
    "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[incidents]}])["Wireframe"]
pointsToMesh[data_] := 
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
mr1 = MeshRegion@
  ToElementMesh[bmesh, "MaxCellMeasure" -> Infinity, "MeshOrder" -> 1]
ℛ = 
 RegionProduct[mr1, pointsToMesh@Subdivide[0, 0.3, 1]]
Export["extrude2.obj", ℛ]
```

[image: FEM approach]

We can verify that this object file also can be read by MeshLab:

[image: MeshLab FEM]

## Update in response to a comment

In the comments, the OP requested a workflow for a data set that contained holes. Unfortunately, the data do not represent points on a boundary, rather they represent the interior points (146,253). Therefore a different approach must be used.

There appear to be three main holes along with a number of holes that appear to be spurious. The following shows an image analysis approach to clean up and mesh a 2D data set.

```
data2d = Import["complete_extrude.xyz", "Table"];
Graphics[{Black, PointSize[0.0025], Point[data2d]}]
{xr, yr} = {MinMax[data2d[[All, 1]]], MinMax[data2d[[All, 2]]]};
image = DeleteSmallComponents@
  GaussianFilter[
   ColorNegate@
    Binarize@
     Rasterize[Graphics[{Black, PointSize[0.0125], Point[data2d]}], 
      "Image"], 5]
im = ImageMesh[image, DataRange -> {xr, yr}]
(*Use RegionProduct to extrude mesh*)
ℛ = 
 RegionProduct[im, pointsToMesh@Subdivide[0, 0.3, 1]]
```

[image: Image mesh approach]

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. When i am using delFn i get this error Syntax::sntxf: "{data,n}|" cannot be followed by "->Delete[data,Partition[Ordering[Norm/@(Rest@(#-RotateRight[#]))&@data,n],1]]". I use mathematica 12. Do you know how to fix it

Comment: @NeAr I am on 12.2.  You could try refreshing the kernel or try using `data2da = 
  Delete[data2d, 
   Partition[
    Ordering[Norm /@ (Rest@(# - RotateRight[#])) &@data2d, -6], 1]];
data2db = 
  Delete[data2da, 
   Partition[
    Ordering[Norm /@ (Rest@(# - RotateRight[#])) &@data2da, 700], 1]];` without the function directly.

Comment: Thanks its working! A follow-up question from my side. How would you approach this problem when we additionally have a hole in the object. The original list of points is given here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5eoj74397vlao3/complete_extrude.xyz?dl=0   The problem with holes is that the in-built function FindShortestTour doesnt work anymore as intended. I dont know how to apply your solution in this complicated case

Comment: @NeAr these data appear to contain the interior points whereas your first example contained the boundary points. Therefore, you will need a new approach. The new example also appears to contain three major holes along with many smaller holes. I do not know what is real and what is an artifact. Probably the best bet would be to use image analysis to process the data and then use `ImageMesh`to create the 2D mesh.

Comment: Awesome, you helped alot :)

Answer (score 4):

```
n = .3;
pts = RandomReal[{-4, 4}, {10, 2}];
reg2 = DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[{-4, 4}, {10, 2}]];
reg2bd = RegionBoundary[reg2];
reg1 = BoundaryMeshRegion[{{0}, {n}}, Point[{{1}, {2}}]];
reg1bd = MeshRegion[{{0}, {n}}, Point[{1, 2}]];
HighlightMesh[RegionProduct[reg2bd, reg1], {Style[1, {Thick, Black}]}];
HighlightMesh[RegionProduct[reg2, reg1bd], {Style[1, None]}];
Show[%%, %]
```

[image]

Test nonconvex region.

```
n = .3;
pts = RandomReal[{-4, 4}, {10, 2}];
reg2 = Polygon[RandomPoint[Annulus[{3, 4}], 10]];
reg2reg = reg2 // Region;
reg2bd = RegionBoundary[reg2reg];
reg1 = BoundaryMeshRegion[{{0}, {n}}, Point[{{1}, {2}}]];
reg1bd = MeshRegion[{{0}, {n}}, Point[{1, 2}]];
HighlightMesh[RegionProduct[reg2bd, reg1], {Style[1, {Thick, Black}]}];
HighlightMesh[RegionProduct[reg2, reg1bd], {Style[1, None]}];
Show[%%, %]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you have mentioned yourself, this works for convex region pretty well but in my case (see link above) i have a non-convex region which fails

Comment: @NeAr For some reason, I can't download your .xyz file, so I have to use `RandomPoint` and `RandomReal`, perhaps you can add some minimal examples.