# Extrude 3D list with thickness n

Tags: list-manipulation, finite-element-method, mesh

I have a 3 dimensional list of points which i would like to extrude in z coordinate with thickness n, i.e. z_{i} -> z_{i}+n for all points in z. There is a similar question concerning 2d list where the z coordinate is by default zero and obtains the thickness n, see [Extrude two dimensional list with thickness n](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242519/extrude-two-dimensional-list-with-thickness-n) .  The example list can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/mjewq4wnqlqczjb/AdvancedCase.xyz?dl=0

Generally speaking the object can contain holes and can also be an inclined planar. If someone can help me out i would much appreciate it.

Comment: I think a big part of this question, like with the other one, is "how do you clean up the point cloud and produce a (2-dimensional extrudable) mesh in the first place", which is a nontrivial problem.

Comment: Do you have a list with 3D points or a 3 dimensional list of points (2 or 3D)?  If the first: `(#+n)&/@ list` will add n to the z components.

Comment: If you really want to attract more attention, I would suggest making the problem more attractive. A *minimal* working example would probably help. The plot of the data below is not encouraging.

Comment: Problem is posed insufficient. From the curated answer this is a question for a projection into the xy-plane and the rather noisy data is declared to be without noise. This is very bad question pratice!

Answer (score 7):

Since no MWE has been forthcoming, here is a demonstration that this functionality is built into `ListPlot3D`.

Here's some data:

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, Sin[x + 3 Cos[y]]/2}, {x, -3., 3, 0.1}, {y, -3., 3, 0.1}],
   1];
Dimensions@data

(*  {3721, 3}  *)

ListPlot3D[data]
```

[image]

To get vertical thickness added, use the `NormalsFunction` option.  The thickness is added in the direction of the normal vectors it returns.  We can even punch a hole in the mesh with the `RegionFunction` option.

```
DiscretizeGraphics@ListPlot3D[data,
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 > 2.5],
  Method -> {"Extrusion" -> 0.5}, (* set thickness *)
  NormalsFunction -> ({0., 0., 1.} &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Where do I find such documentation for ListPlot3D with  Method -> {"Extrusion" -> 0.5}.

Comment: @SteffenJaeschke It first showed up as a separate option [`Extrusion -> 0.5`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55021/4999), which still works. I found the option by resolving the `"ThickSurface"` plot theme for `Plot3D`, although it works for `ListPlot3D`: ``Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["ThickSurface", ListPlot3D]``. While `"ThickSurface"` appears in the documentation, the way it is accomplished through the `"Extrusion"` suboption is not.  The `Extrusion` option is also undocumented, is not among `Options@ListPlot3D`, and therefore shows up as red when used.

Answer (score 7):

As has been mentioned in the comments and previous posts [243594](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/243594/61809), the data has poor signal-to-noise and therefore requires some cleanup.

## Import and view the data

First, we will import the data and [`Standardize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Standardize.html)it so that the points are centered on the mean.

```
d = Import["AdvancedCase.xyz", "Table"];
d1 = First@d;
(*Translate data to be centered about mean of points*)
d = Standardize[d, Mean, 1 &];
offset = d1 - First@d;
CoordinateBounds[d]
ListPointPlot3D[d, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: Original data]

From the  ListPointPlot3D and the CoordinatesBounds, we see that about 20 times the variation is contained in the X and Y coordinates. Therefore, fitting the data to a plane will provide a first-order correction and capture much of the variation in the Z-direction.

## Fitting the data to a plane

The following code will fit the data to a plane and rotate it so that the normal aligns with a new z-axis.

```
(*Find plane that best fits data*)
lm = LinearModelFit[d, {x, y}, {x, y}];
(*Extract plane normal*)
normal = Normalize[{-#2, -#3, 1}] & @@ lm["BestFitParameters"];
(*Find transform function that rotates normal to new z-axis*)
tr = Last@
   FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, normal}];
(*Rotate extrusion axis into new coordinate system*)
npz = tr[{0, 0, 1}];
(*Find inverse transform*)
itr = tr // InverseFunction;
(*Transform and plot the data*)
td = tr[d];
ListPointPlot3D[td, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: Transformed data]

If we compare this ListPlot image in the new coordinate system to the previous ListPlot image, we see that we have removed much of the variation in the Z direction. We will assume that the surface is flat and that we are only concerned with the X and Y directions. Now, the problem is 2D and it will be easier to apply filters to clean up the data.

## Cleanup of 2D data

We will convert the three-dimensional data into two-dimensional data and use image processing techniques to clean up the data as we did in the previously linked answer.

```
data2d = td[[All, {1, 2}]];
Graphics[{Black, PointSize[0.0025], Point[data2d]}]
{xr, yr} = {MinMax[data2d[[All, 1]]], MinMax[data2d[[All, 2]]]};
image = DeleteSmallComponents@
  GaussianFilter[
   ColorNegate@
    Binarize@
     Rasterize[Graphics[{Black, PointSize[0.0125], Point[data2d]}], 
      "Image"], 5]
im = ImageMesh[image, DataRange -> {xr, yr}]
```

[image: Image mesh]

## Conversion to Quad mesh and extrusion

Since I am not quite sure how to handle prisms, we will convert the 2D mesh into quads and then extrude the elements along the new $z'$-axis. Then, we will rotate the coordinates back into the old coordinate system and produce the final MeshRegion.

```
(*Import required FEM package*)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
(*Install MeshTools*)
(*Uncomment if not installed*)
(*ResourceFunction["GitHubInstall"]["c3m-labs","MeshTools"]*)
Needs["MeshTools`"]
(*Convert Triangle mesh into Quad mesh*)
Print["Smoothed Quad mesh"]
(mesh2d = 
   SmoothenMesh[
    TriangleToQuadMesh[
     ToElementMesh[im, "MeshOrder" -> 1]]])["Wireframe"]
len = 0.3;(*Extrusion length*)
(*Extract and extrude coordinates*)
crd = mesh2d["Coordinates"];
ncrd = Length@crd;
(*Convert 2D coordinates into 3D*)
crd3d = crd /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y, 0};
crd3dextrude = crd3d /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {x, y, z} + len npz;
(*Join coordinates an inverse transform into original coordinate \
system*)
crd3d = # + offset & /@ itr[Join[crd3d, crd3dextrude]];
(*Convert quad elements into hexahedral elements*)
inc = ElementIncidents[mesh2d["MeshElements"]];
inc3d = First@(inc /. {i_, j_, k_, l_} :> {i, j, k, l, i + ncrd, 
       j + ncrd, k + ncrd, l + ncrd});
(*Create element mesh and convert into mesh region*)
Print["Mesh region"]
mesh3d = MeshRegion@
  ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd3d, 
   "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[inc3d]}]
```

[image: Final mesh region]

Comment: Thanks Tim, your answer is exactly what im looking for. There is one strange thing though, when Im uploading the original data and your result in meshlab, I observed that the coordinates changed.

Comment: @NeAr I `Standardized` the data (i.e., centered the data on the center-of-mass of the data points).  Then, I was only thinking of a rotation transformation on the data points since translation had been taken care of.  It was easier for me to think that way.  It would not be difficult to add the translation back to your original coordinate system, but I am going to be occupied for a few hours.

Comment: @NeAr I shifted the mesh back to the original offset.

Comment: Maybe at this point Im asking too much, but i will give it a try. Is it possible to make an option if the user wants to consider the object without holes, i.e. an ideal object?

Comment: @NeAr If you want to fill in the holes, the simplest way is to use `"RegionHoles->None` Like so:  `(mesh2d = 
   SmoothenMesh[
    TriangleToQuadMesh[
     ToElementMesh[im, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
      "MeshOrder" -> 1]]])["Wireframe"]`.  Since you are using MeshLab, you can decimate the mesh to reduce the triangle count.

Comment: @NeAr Hmm... First you are asking about 3D list, but after Tim  Laska answer I don't understand your question. Why you asking about 3D while then use 2D?

Comment: @TimLaska Well, it is nice answer for set of 2D points imbedding in 3D (+1). But it seems that we discussed set of 3D points.  May be in this case it does not matter, but in general case there are different algorithms for 3D points and 2D points.

Comment: @AlexTrounev there should be more exposition in the question about the system the OP is trying to solve so we can make better assumptions. Since I had answered two of the OP's previous questions, I knew they were interested in the extrusion of a thin flat wafer ($n=0.3$). The peak-to-peak variation of the points about the fitted 3D plane is about 5X that amount. Needless to say, it will be difficult to find an algorithm that works well with such low signal-to-noise and large aspect ratios. My approach simply applied a first-order correction to the z data, but it is not general.

Comment: @NeAr   What are you commented about? Please read my question and Michel E2 as well under my answer. There are no comments from your side.  Also you are not explain your problem for community, that you just need average plane for your set of points. From the other side there is visible curvature in your data, so it is not a plane. How we should suggest what you need if you not explain your problem?

Comment: @TimLaska In the case of a inclined planar the object will not be extruded along the z-axis, hence it looks kinda weird. Do you know how to resolve this.

Comment: @NeAr since I used two reference frames (i.e., the original coordinate system and the new coordinate system where I aligned the new z-axis with the plane normal), we need to be clear is it the $z$ or $z'$ axis.  I believe I extruded it along the z-axis in the original frame.

Comment: @TimLaska Here is an example of a inclined planar https://www.dropbox.com/s/spagg4l2mncb5b2/wesel_wall_inclined.xyz?dl=0 Unfortunately i can only say that if i extrude this list the lines are not horizontal compared to the example of "AdvancedCase.xyz" where the extruded lines are perpendicular to z axis. One can visualize with meshlab to see what i mean

Comment: @NeAr If you replace `npz = tr[{0, 0, 1}];` with `npz = {0, 0, 1};`, does that give you what you need?

Answer (score 0):

This is illustration how to do it with `ListPointPlot3D` and to show what kind of points we have to plot. Since list uploaded on https://www.dropbox.com/s/mjewq4wnqlqczjb/AdvancedCase.xyz?dl=0 is not structured we can't use it with `ListPlot3D`. Also there is some noise in these data. Therefore we use first as Steffen recommends

```
data = Import["...\\AdvancedCase.txt", "Data"]
```

Then plot `data` as

```
ListPointPlot3D[data]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Now we can prepare second list with

```
n = 2; data1 = Table[data[[i]] + {0, 0, n}, {i, Length[data]}];
```

We can also plot `data` and `data1` together

```
ListPointPlot3D[{data, data1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Figure 2]

As we understand the question is about how we can prepare 3D object from two set of points `data` and `data1`. The simplest way to extrude `data` along `z` is prepare set of solid primitives (same as in FEM). We take small subset from `data` and plot (in this example `n=5`)

```
L = Length[data];

dataT = Take[data, {1, L, 25}];

g = Graphics3D[
  Table[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, LightBlue]], Blue, Opacity[.5], 
    Cylinder[{dataT[[i]], dataT[[i]] + {0, 0, 5}}, .2]}, {i, 
    Length[dataT]}], Boxed -> False, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: @NeAr Is there noise in you data or it is only looks like noise?

Comment: @NeAr How do you ***define*** the holes?

Answer (score -1):

Mathematica knows the xyz-file type: [XYZ](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/XYZ.html).

```
givenlist=Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/mjewq4wnqlqczjb/AdvancedCase.xyz?dl=0"]
```

from this documentation page. There rest works as above. But this fails.

Loading this as ASCII shows this:

13.2577219009 -45.3633308411 136.8547973633

13.5088977814 -45.2704734802 136.8559722900

10.8333778381 -45.8802146912 136.6637573242

10.9468536377 -46.1600723267 136.5761871338

13.1572370529 -45.1396865845 136.6828918457

10.7912321091 -45.7505187988 136.6897125244

...

This is already a three-dimensional list. Rename the file type to txt and it is imported.

```
Import["./../AdvancedCase.txt", "Data"]
ListPlot3D[%20]
```

[image: ListPlot3D]

If the given surface would not have this much and heavy noise then [ExtrudeMesh](http://FEMAddOns/ref/ExtrudeMesh) is the solution. This shows how to extrude a `Rectangle` into a mesh volume in two steps.

allows making a control check whether enough points are considered for the convex hull.

Perhaps this is what You like:

```
ListPlot3D[%20, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image: ListPlot3D with shards]
This is interpolation-free and assumes nothing that may spike. Each value is displayed on a shared basis. The extrusion is now taken to a common base plain. This looks rather different from top and bottom than from the sides views:

[image]

There are several types of substructures in the various subregion.

[image]

This shows this concave:

```
ListPlot3D[140 - %20, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", Filling -> Bottom, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

ListPlot3D[list, Method -> {"Extrusion" -> 0.5},
NormalsFunction -> ({0., 0., 1.} &)]

A nice solution too is

```
ListPlot3D[list/5, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 Method -> {"Extrusion" -> 0.1}, NormalsFunction -> ({0., 0., 1.} &), 
 ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors"]
```

[image: solution]

I added a scale down factor 0.2 and suppresssed interpolation. This is now a plain extrusion and has a structured downside.

I can not find this method option in my Mathematica documentation. So gratefull thanks to [michael-e2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)!!!

OK! There is a lot of information now added by the comments.

This is a comparison for a methodology smoothing the supposed surface:

```
ListPointPlot3D[{data, 
  BilateralFilter[data, 2, .5, MaxIterations -> 25]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}]
```

[image: smoothing by bilateral filerting]

This question offers the smoothing built-ins in Mathematica: [remove noise from data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124928/remove-noise-from-data)

So some smoothing gives another impression of the given surfaces:

```
ListPointPlot3D[MeanShiftFilter[data, 5, .5, MaxIterations -> 25], 
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}]
```

[image]

From straight line to steps. But some lines get more straight. Other lines appear and some inner points set appear.

[image]

It is time do ask again for more information about the intents of the question. The smoothed structures seem to fit to my first preconception of it.

The change is

```
ListPlot3D[MeanShiftFilter[data, 5, .5, MaxIterations -> 25], 
 Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", , Method -> {"Extrusion" -> 0.1},
  NormalsFunction -> ({0., 0., 1.} &)]
```

[image: proximum]

Nice to communicate whether this is the right direction.

```
ListPlot3D[MeanShiftFilter[data, 5, .5, MaxIterations -> 25], 
 Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", Method -> {"Extrusion" -> 0.1}, 
 NormalsFunction -> ({0., 0., 1.} &)]
```

[image: new view of the data set]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. If we assume that we dont have noise at all it still gives you an extrude of a convex region. In our case we a concave region.

Comment: This is a misguiding comment!